# External monitor shows pointer but no background or application screens on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, xfce

Pertinent output from `inxi -Fxxxrz`

**System**:    Kernel: 5.4.0-65-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop:
Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.13  info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 1.30.0
Distro: Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
**Machine:**   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: G5 5590  Chassis: type: 10
Mobo: Dell model: 0CNDTP v: A00  UEFI: Dell v: 1.14.0 date: 10/20/2020
status: Full
**CPU:**       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3
sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 62399 Speed: 1473 MHz min/max: 800/2600 MHz
Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1473 2: 1624 3: 1520 4: 1654 5: 1219 6: 1388 7: 1164
8: 1303 9: 1490 10: 2036 11: 1224 12: 1683
**Graphics:**  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v:
kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3e9b
Device-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile] vendor: Dell driver: nouveau
v: kernel bus  ID: 01:00.0  chip ID: 10de:1f11
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
direct render: Yes
**External Monitor:** HP VH240a

Dual boot with Windows 10

The laptop screen displays correctly. The external monitor shows up on the Display setting, and I can see the pointer when I move the mouse over to that monitor, but nothing else will display, no background, no application screens.It works fine when I boot up in Windows 10.

I have not found any issue/answer pair that fits this criteria.

[image]

UPDATE:

I hooked up to another monitor, and it immediately defaulted to mirrored screens with both showing up. Thinking that the problem was solved, I set it to extended mode, and the screen went blank again. Trying to go back to mirrored mode didn't work again.

Comment: I wonder if switching to nvidia drivers could make a difference. Also, I'm sorry, but what GUI theme are you using?

Comment: I will be using the NVIDIA GPU for deep neural network training, so need to keep that fully available for that purpose. The GUI theme I'm using right now is simply the default from the install. Pls see the update.